# android activity switch direction

Tags: android, screen, slide, direction

when switching between two activities, screen slides between right to left. When I press back key, screen slides from right to left. Is it a way that when I press back key from an activity to change screen sliding direction?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807131/new-activity-in-android-enter-from-the-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Danny's solution could be made to work but it is overly complicated. The key method you want to learn about is overridePendingTransition().

Here is main activity that I mocked up to use it. I made it transition vertically just to show that you can make transformations in any direction you like:

```
package com.superliminal.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ScreenTransitionTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnForwards = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForwards);
        btnForwards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity currentActivity = (Activity) v.getContext();
                Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity, NewScreen.class);
                // Tell the new activity how return when finished.
                i.putExtra("anim id in", R.anim.down_in);
                i.putExtra("anim id out", R.anim.down_out);
                currentActivity.startActivity(i);
                // This makes the new screen slide up as it fades in
                // while the current screen slides up as it fades out.
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.up_in, R.anim.up_out);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the new screen:

```
package com.superliminal.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_screen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        // Use exiting animations specified by the parent activity if given
        // Translate left if not specified.
        overridePendingTransition(
            getIntent().getIntExtra("anim id in", R.anim.left_in),
            getIntent().getIntExtra("anim id out", R.anim.left_out));
    }
}
```

Your layout files can be anything you like. You don't need a wrapper layer. Here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#990000" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Activity" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnForwards"
        android:text="Forward" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my new_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#009900" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="New Screen. Use back button to return." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The only other things you need are animation XML files that you put in the res/anim folder.

up_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

up_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

down_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

down_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="1000"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. After you capture the back key event, or any other event that causes a new screen to load, you can control the direction that a screen slides but it is not intuitively obvious on how to do it.  The outer most layer of the layout will never be animated by your code so you may need to place your layout inside a wrapper.  You will also have to call the animation code from inside of onCreate() of the screen where you wish for animation to occur.

If you make yourself a project named "ScreenTransitionLab" using "android.example" as the package, you can use the following to have a working example that will help you understand how to accomplish what you want to do.  It currently is set for top and bottom transitions but can easily be modified to use left and right transitions.

Main screen that was modified so the whole screen will slide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
  Wrapper layout whose children are to be animated. The outermost layout
  used by an activity can never be animated, so this wrapper is needed.
  The wrapper layout is given a different color so it can be
  distinguished from the layout that is animated.
 -->
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#0000FF"
>
 <!-- Actual layout that is animated. -->
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FF0000"
 >
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello" />
  <Button
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/btnForwards"
   android:text="Forwards" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

New screen that was modified so that the whole screen will slide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
  Wrapper layout whose children are to be animated. The outermost layout
  used by an activity can never be animated, so this wrapper is needed.
  The wrapper layout is given a different color so it can be
  distinguished from the layout that is animated.
 -->
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#0000FF"
>
 <!-- Actual layout that is animated. -->
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FF0000"
 >
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello" />
  <Button
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/btnForwards"
   android:text="Forwards" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ScreenTransitionsLab activity that is animated when the "Backwards" button is clicked in NewScreen activity:

```
package android.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ScreenTransitionLab extends Activity {
    // Layout fields
    protected LinearLayout mainLayout;
    public static Button btnForwards = null;
    public static Activity currentActivity;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentActivity = this;

        /*
         * This creates View objects from the xml file. The xml file should
         * define all views and all static attributes.
         */
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main,
                null);

        btnForwards = (Button) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnForwards);
        btnForwards.setOnClickListener(forwardsOnClickListener);

        UIHelper.setSlideDirection(mainLayout, UIHelper.bottom);

        /*
         * Use the Layout that contains the View objects that were modified to
         * create screen that will be shown after activity is done processing
         * instead of the xml file. The Layout will contain all of the views and
         * static attributes that were defined in the xml file plus all of the
         * dynamic attributes that were defined in the code above.
         */
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener forwardsOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity currentActivity = (Activity) v.getContext();
            Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity, NewScreen.class);
            currentActivity.startActivity(i);

            /*
             * Remove activity that is no longer current from the activity stack
             * to prevent the application from bloating.
             */
            currentActivity.finish();
        }
    };

}
```

NewScreen activity that is animated when the "Forwards" button is clicked in ScreenTransitionsLab activity:

```
package android.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class NewScreen extends Activity {
    protected LinearLayout mainLayout;
    public static Button btnBackwards = null;
    public static Activity currentActivity;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentActivity = this;

        /*
         * This creates View objects from the xml file. The xml file should
         * define all views and all static attributes.
         */
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.new_screen, null);

        btnBackwards = (Button) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnBackwards);
        btnBackwards.setOnClickListener(backwardsOnClickListener);

        UIHelper.setSlideDirection(mainLayout, UIHelper.top);

        /*
         * Use the Layout that contains the View objects that were modified to
         * create screen that will be shown after activity is done processing
         * instead of the xml file. The Layout will contain all of the views and
         * static attributes that were defined in the xml file plus all of the
         * dynamic attributes that were defined in the code above.
         */
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener backwardsOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity currentActivity = (Activity) v.getContext();
            Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity, ScreenTransitionLab.class);
            currentActivity.startActivity(i);

            /*
             * Remove activity that is no longer current from the activity stack
             * to prevent the application from bloating.
             */
            currentActivity.finish();
        }
    };

}
```

UIHelper class that actually performs the aninmation:

```
package android.example;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

public class UIHelper {
    public static final int top = 1;
    public static final int bottom = 2;
    public static final int left = 3;
    public static final int right = 4;

    /**
     * Set direction that children in the panel will slide in from when next
     * displayed.
     * 
     * @param panel
     *            {@link ViewGroup} whose children will be slid in from the
     *            specified direction when the panel is next displayed.
     * @param fromDirection
     *            Primitive int indicating the direction to slide the children
     *            of the panel from.
     */
    public static void setSlideDirection(ViewGroup panel, int fromDirection) {
        float fromX = 0;
        float toX = 0;
        float fromY = 0;
        float toY = 0;

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        animation.setDuration(100);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        switch (fromDirection) {
        case top:
            fromX = 0.00f;
            toX = 0.00f;
            fromY = -1.00f;
            toY = 0.00f;
            break;
        case bottom:
            fromX = 0.00f;
            toX = 0.00f;
            fromY = 1.00f;
            toY = 0.00f;
            break;
        case left:
            fromX = -1.00f;
            toX = 0.00f;
            fromY = 0.00f;
            toY = 0.00f;
            break;
        default:
            fromX = 1.00f;
            toX = 0.00f;
            fromY = 0.00f;
            toY = 0.00f;
            break;
        }

        animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, fromX,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, toX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                fromY, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, toY);
        animation.setDuration(200);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
                set, 0.25f);
        panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }

}
```