# Make activity transition like ViewPager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-animation

I want to **startActivity with transition like ViewPager**. I mean Activity A pushes Activity B from one side to another. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807131/new-activity-in-android-enter-from-the-side) and tried to implement the transition but it isn't similar to ViewPager.

slide_up1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="500"/>

</set>
```

slide_up2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >


    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" 
        android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
        android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="0"/>

    </set>
```

Call it.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_up1, R.animator.slide_up2);
```

**Edit:**

Solution for my case.

slide_up1.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         >
        <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="1000"/>
       </set>
```

slide_up2.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         >
      <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%"
       android:duration="1000" />
    </set>
```

Comment: What is different then? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the XML to this

animation1

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="1000"/>
       </set>
```

and animation2

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="1000" />
    </set>
```

and this is for right to left

after that you can call it using override pending transition like you use for the code in your question like this

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1, R.anim.animation2);
```